# How to use cluster nodes in Test kitchen chef i need to install hadoop cluster with chef with test kitchen for testing

Tags: hadoop, chef-infra, test-kitchen

How create and use as a cluster nodes using Test kitchen -- Chef

Want to install the Hadoop cluster using test kitchen but how can I use multiple nodes with inter communication in Test kitchen

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately kitchen has no generic way to do this right now. I wrote a Chef community RFC to document what needs to be added to support it, but currently it will be an uphill battle. Your best bet is probably the vagrant driver with manually specified IPs, but even this can be hard. If you join the Chef community slack team, ping me (also coderanger there) and I can try to help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify private network in Kitchen and assign IP addresses to each node, something like:

```
- name: foo-node
    driver:
      network:
        - ["private_network", { ip: "1.2.3.4" }]
    provisioner:
      policyfile_path: policyfiles/foobar.rb
    attributes:
      foo: 'bar
```

Keeping in mind that you won't have DNS and you'll have to add entries to each node `/etc/hosts` file, you will be able to make the VMs to communicate between them and form a cluster.

Finally, be careful with the interfaces Hadoop binds to, because it probably won't bind to private network one, making the communication between key components like *namenode* and *secondary namenode* impossible.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Test-Kitchen is just a wrapper over container technology of your choice. I would go with LXD then. If you attach all your containers to the same network (lxdbr0), they will be able to see each other. So all you have to do is configure Test-Kitchen to start multiple containers.